# How Can I Solve this Nuxt npm run build error

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, namecheap

Anyone have an idea why I'm getting this error. I'm trying to deploy a nuxt app to namecheap following a tutorial I found [here](https://jigeshraval.com/en/blog/vue-js/nuxtjs-universal-application-deployment-in-cpanel), when I run npm run build from the node environment I get this error.

```
    events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn /opt/alt/alt-nodejs12/root/usr/bin/node EAGAIN
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:470:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:274:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:470:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'EAGAIN',
  code: 'EAGAIN',
  syscall: 'spawn /opt/alt/alt-nodejs12/root/usr/bin/node',
  path: '/opt/alt/alt-nodejs12/root/usr/bin/node',
  spawnargs: [
    '/home/ultirlgo/nodevenv/mydomain.com/12/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/                                                                                        build/workers/processChild.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@1.0.0 build: `nuxt build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the client@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log                                                                                        ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ultirlgo/.npm/_logs/2021-09-20T14_55_24_751Z-debug.log
```

I actually did check the log but could'nt figure out the problem.
Here is the error in my log.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/opt/alt/alt-nodejs14/root/usr/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/opt/alt/alt-nodejs14/root/usr/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.13
3 info using node@v14.17.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle client@1.0.0~predev: client@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle client@1.0.0~dev: client@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle client@1.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle client@1.0.0~dev: PATH: /opt/alt/alt-nodejs14/root/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules.bundled/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/ultirlgo/mydomain.com/node_modules/.bin:/opt/alt/alt-nodejs14/root/usr/bin:/home/ultirlgo/nodevenv/mydomain.com/14/bin:/opt/alt/alt-nodejs14/root/usr/bin:/home/ultirlgo/nodevenv/mydomain.com/14/lib/bin/:/home/ultirlgo/perl5/bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/opt/lua/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/home/ultirlgo/bin
9 verbose lifecycle client@1.0.0~dev: CWD: /home/ultirlgo/mydomain.com
10 silly lifecycle client@1.0.0~dev: Args: [ '-c', 'nuxt --hostname mydomain.com --port 49000' ]
11 silly lifecycle client@1.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle client@1.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: client@1.0.0 dev: `nuxt --hostname mydomain.com --port 49000`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/opt/alt/alt-nodejs14/root/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules.bundled/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:375:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/opt/alt/alt-nodejs14/root/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules.bundled/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:375:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid client@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/ultirlgo/mydomain.com
16 verbose Linux 2.6.32-954.3.5.lve1.4.80.el6.x86_64
17 verbose argv "/opt/alt/alt-nodejs14/root/usr/bin/node" "/opt/alt/alt-nodejs14/root/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v14.17.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.13
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error client@1.0.0 dev: `nuxt --hostname mydomain.com --port 49000`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the client@1.0.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Can you please provide us with some more code or relevants files to debug this one? Hard to tell what is buggy here. Also, try to build it locally.

Comment: @rishta I actually did but could make sense of the error in the log. pls pardon my ignorance.

Comment: If you ```npm run generate``` in your project root, does the build complete successfully?

Comment: @S.Ramjit when i tried npm run generate, it didn't build successfully.

Comment: Can you post the error logs in that case? If it doesn't build locally you should try to sort that error out first

Comment: @S.Ramjit The app is working fine on my local machine, its only giving me the error while trying to deploy it to namecheap. npm run build and npm run generate using the node terminal on namecheap gives error. I posted the error I have in the log when I ran npm run build above. thanks

Comment: `npm run generate` is if you do have `target: 'static'`. `npm run build` is if you do have `target: 'server'` (default). You should not run both. Depending of the use case, you need either `npm run generate/build`, then run `npm run start` locally. If you do have the error locally, please fix it first. Btw, sharing your `nuxt.config.js` will help us. This and any other relevant files.

Comment: the app is running fine on my local machine but just can't get it to work on my hosting server. here is test app I created with similar configuration to what I was trying to deploy https://github.com/mykedee/test-app @kissu Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe you have npm cache problem. Delete your package-lock.json file and node_modules folder. Then do npm cache clean

```
npm cache clean --force
```

do `npm install` after cleaning the cache

and run again

Comment: I did that but still got the same error.